# Elasticsearch autocomplete keywords with spaces

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a mapping and autocomplete functionality that would allow searching for keywords with spaces. Right now if i search for first word - it's works well. But if i try to search for second one (like. i.e lastname) it doesn't return any values.

i have mapping and settings like.

```json
PUT /autocomplete
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 20
        },
        "word_joiner": {
          "type": "word_delimiter",
          "catenate_all": true
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "word_joiner",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "contents": {
        "type": "completion",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /autocomplete/_doc
{
  "contents": [
    "Test search"
  ]
}
```

And if i run

```json
POST /autocomplete/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "contents": {
      "text": "search",
      "completion": {
        "field": "contents",
        "skip_duplicates": true

      }
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't return any values. I've tried various types, analyzers - still no success.

Can you please help me in finding what's wrong here?

ES 7.9

Comment: I think the main problem is the `standard` tokenizer, because that will split your input into tokens whereas you want to keep them together.

Comment: What should i use instead?

Comment: Try the keyword tokenizer, also I'm not sure about the usage of the `word_delimiter` token filter in this context

Comment: Unfortunately, it gives me the same behaviour...

Comment: Did you completely reindex your data after changing the analyzer?

Comment: yes, i remove index before each change